# Refresh MVCContrib Grid after performing a row action

Tags: jquery, mvccontrib-grid

I am using MVCContrib mostly for the paging, sorting, and filtering aspects. My grid contains all of the addresses in our mailing list application (backend only). The user can delete, activate, and inactivate list members, so there are action links for these options on each row. Using jQuery, I am capturing that click and performing other things like display notification of the action is completed.

Because of this, the problem I have is how do I refresh the grid after I perform these actions so the user can see the results? On a delete, I can hide the row. What can I do for when a person activates/deactivates an email? Just use jQuery to update the value in the table that shows the status?

```
// Activate the email address
$(".ActivateLink").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    var i = id.indexOf("#");
    id = id.substring(i + 1);
    $.ajaxSetup({ 'async': false });
    $.post("/List/Activate", { "id": id }, function(data) {
        $(".message").text(data.message).addClass("notice");
    }, "json");
    return false;
});
```

My Controller Action:

```
    //
    // POST: /List/Activate
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Activate(int id)
    {
        string message = String.Empty;
        db.ActivateEventEmail(id, ref message);
        return Json(new { message = message });
    }
```

My View:

```
<%= Html.Grid(Model.EmailAddressList).Columns(column => {
    column.For("ImageActions").Named("").Sortable(false);
    column.For(a => (a.Email.Length > 30) ? String.Format("{0}...", a.Email.Substring(0, 30)) : a.Email).Encode(true).SortColumnName("Email").Named("Email Address");
    column.For(a => (a.ContactName.Length > 30) ? String.Format("{0}...", a.ContactName.Substring(0, 30)) : a.ContactName).Encode(true).SortColumnName("ContactName").Named("Contact Name");
    column.For(a => a.SignupDate).Named("Signup Date").Format("{0:d}").Attributes(@style => "text-align: right;");
    column.For(a => a.AccountStatus ? "Yes" : "No").SortColumnName("AccountStatus").Named("Active").Attributes(@style => "text-align: center;");
}).Sort(Model.GridSortOptions)
    .Attributes(@class => "table-list", style => "width: 100%;").RowAttributes(c => new MvcContrib.Hash(@class => "gridrow"))
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out.

First of all I just had to add a call to a function I'll have later down the code.

```
// Activate the email address
$(".ActivateLink").live('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    var i = id.indexOf("#");
    id = id.substring(i + 1);
    $.ajaxSetup({ 'async': false });
    $.post("/List/Activate", { "id": id }, function(data) {
        refreshTable();
        $(".message").text(data.message).addClass("notice");
    }, "json");
    return false;
});
```

The above controller action, I don't touch and the view I had above, I don't touch. The new javascript function I create is as follows:

```
    function refreshTable() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            async: false,
            cache: false
        });
        $.get('<%= Url.Action("Index", "List", new { filterText = Model.FilterText, filterActive = Model.FilterActive, filterGroup = Model.FilterGroup }) %>',
        function(response) {
            $(".table-list").replaceWith(response)
        });
    };
```

Make sure to have the `cache: false` in there. IE likes to pull data from cache and really make a mess of things.

On my Index action I changed from `return View(emailListGrid);` to

```
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("EmailMaint", emailListGrid);
        else
            return View(emailListGrid);
```

Comment: So do you send the entire grid back and fourth between between client and server?   I'm in the same boat as you except that I want to simply add a new row to the grid.  So my "refreshTable" method would just add the model from the response instead of replacing the entire grid.

Comment: Yes, the entire grid is sent. I am not sure how to add a row to a MVCContrib table.